# mysqldump is not dumping any table

Tags: database, backup, mysql

I can't manage to backup my MySQL database. I use the following command:

```
mysqldump --user=user --password=password db > db.sql
```

This is what the output file looks like:

```
-- MySQL dump 10.11
--
-- Host: localhost    Database: db
-- ------------------------------------------------------
-- Server version   5.0.96-community

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;
/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;
/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;
/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
```

That's it. Not any `CREATE TABLE` and not any `INSERT`... I also noticed in posts for similar problems that there always was a `-- Dump completed on YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` at the end of the output, which is not the case here. My username and my password are correct and the user has all possible privileges.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Does it work if you try it using the `root` user?

Comment: Can you try `mysqldump` after doing a mysql repair. Ex: `mysqlcheck --auto-repair db_name`

Comment: What privileges have the used user?

Comment: I unfortunately don't have access to the `root` user. Also, I have to run all these commands through a PHP script, since my host denied my request to enable shell access on my account... Concerning the user, I gave it all privileges for testing purposes, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since asking this question, my web host deactivated the `shell_exec()` command, so now I'm using a PHP script to backup my database. Here's the function I'm using:

```
function backup_tables($host, $user, $pass, $name, $tables='*', $backup_path) {
    $link = mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass);
    mysql_select_db($name,$link);

    //get all of the tables
    if($tables == '*') {
        $tables = array();
        $result = mysql_query('SHOW TABLES');

        while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
            $tables[] = $row[0];
        }
    }
    else {
        $tables = is_array($tables) ? $tables : explode(', ',$tables);
    }

    $droptables = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ';

    for ($i = sizeof($tables) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
        $droptables .= '`' . $tables[$i] . '`';
        if ($i > 0) {
            $droptables .= ', ';
        } else {
            $droptables .= ';';
        }
    }

    //cycle through
    foreach($tables as $table) {
        $result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM '.$table);
        $num_fields = mysql_num_fields($result);

        // $droptables.= '`' . $table . '`, ';
        $row2 = mysql_fetch_row(mysql_query('SHOW CREATE TABLE '.$table));
        $data .= "\n\n".$row2[1].";\n\n";

        for ($i = 0; $i < $num_fields; $i++) {
            while($row = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
                $data .= 'INSERT INTO '.$table.' VALUES(';

                for ($j = 0; $j < $num_fields; $j++) {
                    if (isset($row[$j])) {
                        $row[$j] = addslashes($row[$j]);
                        $row[$j] = ereg_replace("\n","\\n",$row[$j]);
                        $data .= '"'.$row[$j].'"' ;
                    } else {
                        $data .= 'NULL';
                    }

                    if ($j < ($num_fields-1)) {
                        $data .= ',';
                    }
                }

                $data .= ");\n";
            }
        }

        $data .= "\n\n\n";
    }

    $return = $droptables . $return;

    //save file
    $date = date('Ymd-His');
    $filename = 'db-backup-' . $date . '.sql';
    $handle = fopen($backup_path.$filename,'w+');
    fwrite($handle, utf8_encode($return));
    fclose($handle);

    $gzfile = $filename . '.gz';
    $handle = gzopen($backup_path.$gzfile, 'w9');
    gzwrite($handle, file_get_contents($backup_path.$filename));
    gzclose($handle);
}
```

Example usage: `backup_tables('localhost','user','pass','database', 'users, posts, comments, subscriptions', '/home/user/db_backups/');`. You just have to remember to put the tables with foreign keys at the end of the list.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
mysqldump -u username -p DB_Name > dumpfile.sql
```

Comment: I guess it should indeed, however since asking this question my host deactivated the `shell_exec()` command, so I'm using a PHP script to backup my database now. I will post the script in a minute.

Comment: This did not work for me (linux)

Answer (score 1):

Try the same but with the normal mysql command, ie, if you have

```
mysqldump --user=root --password=secret db
```

then try

```
mysql --user=root --password=secret db
```

You should be able to see all tables and data that way, if you're not it's probably the user that's wrong.

Comment: I tried with the `mysql` command, but I'm not even sure it works. Running just `mysql` without any parameters didn't give me any output, which seems weird to me. Also, I have to run all these commands through a PHP script, since my host denied my request to enable shell access on my account... Any ideas?

Comment: How are you running mysqldump without shell access?

Comment: Through a PHP script with `shell_exec()`. I meant to say I have no remote shell access.

Answer (score -4):

Try this mysql -u root -p db_name < mydb.sql

Answer (score -4):

This worked for me. Please try it once

```
mysql -u <username> -p"<password>" database_name < sqlfile.sql
```

Comment: The command you provided is for an import, so it does not answer the question at all.